# Get content from tags in HTML-string with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, rss, titanium

I am working on an application within Titanium, which needs to be deployable for Android and iOS. The app gets it's information via a RSS-feed, I want to show the content of an item in a window. I tried putting it in a `webview` but that's not what I want, I want to be able to determine which element goes where (image, introduction and the content).

For example, this could be the content of an RSS feed item:

```
var content = "<p><img src=\"..." alt=\"dreigtweet\" width=\"280\" height=\"210\" class=\"alignright size-full wp-image-19148\" \/><strong>Een 14-jarig meisje uit Rotterdam is aangehouden omdat ze in een dreigtweet stuurde naar luchtvaartmaatschappij American Airlines. Ze had zich zelf gemeld bij de politie.<\/strong><\/p> <p>Het meisje stuurde zondag onder de naam Sarah het berichtje naar de Amerikaanse luchtvaartmaatschappij, maar die nam de tweet uiterst serieus.<\/p> <p>De tiener schreef: &#8220;Hallo mijn naam is Ibrahim en ik kom uit Afghanistan. Ik maak deel uit van al-Qaeda en op 1 juni ga ik echt iets groots doen, dag.&#8221;<\/p> <p>Ze kreeg vrijwel direct antwoord van American Airlines: &#8220;Sarah, we nemen deze dreigementen zeer serieus. Jouw IP-adres en overige gegevens zullen aan de beveiliging en de FBI worden doorgegeven&#8221;.<\/p> <p>Sarah smeekte in een reeks tweets om vergiffenis, die door een steeds grotere twitterschare werd gevolgd. \u201CIk heb zo&#8217;n spijt, ik ben echt bang nu. Ik maakte een grapje, alsjeblieft doe het niet, ik ben maar een meisje\u201D, schreef de Rotterdamse in verschillende boodschappen.<\/p> <p>In de loop van zondagavond had het meisje er vele duizenden volgers bijgekregen. Inmiddels is haar Twitteraccount opgeschort.<\/p> <p>De Rotterdamse politie wil geen toelichting geven op de aanhouding van het meisje.<\/p> <p>Bron: Rijnmond.nl<\/p> <p><script type=\"text\/javascript\"><!-- google_ad_client = \"ca-pub-4354345434554545\"; \/* ijsselmondenieuws.nl *\/ google_ad_slot = \"434323442\"; google_ad_width = 468; google_ad_height = 60; \/\/--> <\/script><br \/> <script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"http:\/\/pagead2.googlesyndication.com\/pagead\/show_ads.js\"> <\/script><\/p>";
```

I am able to get the text between the `<strong>` tags and put that in a `Titanium.UI.label` like this (or see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5CLL/1/)):

```
function getIntro(html) {
try {
    var intro = html;
    var imgExists = intro.indexOf('<strong>');

    if (imgExists > -1) {
        var i = imgExists + 8;
        intro = intro.substr(i);
        intro = intro.substr(0, intro.indexOf('</strong>'));
        return intro;
    }

} catch (err) {

}
}
```

Then load it into a label like this:

```
var introText = getIntro(postContent);

var intro = Ti.UI.createLabel({
width : '90%',
height : 'auto',
color : '#000',
backgroundColor : '#FFF',
top : '10dp',
textAlign : 'left',
font : {
    fontSize : '16dp',
    fontWeight : 'bold'
},
text : introText
});
```

So that's one obstacle down. The next one is to loop trough the following `<p>` elements and put the text between each of those tags in a new `label` or maybe even a `table row` so I can fake the paragraphs. However I do not know how to get all of the `<p> text here </p>` tags, to loop trough them and add it's content to the window.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I would use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to parse the Content and to access the text inside the paragraphs. [An example](http://jsfiddle.net/CuSp2/):

```
var content = "<div>...</div><p>Text1</p><p>Text2</p><div>...</div>";

// parse Content
content = $($.parseHTML(content, document, false));

// p-Tags
var p = content.filter("p");

// do something with content (for example set the text of <h1> to the joined text of all paragraphes)
$("h1").text($.map(p, $.text).join(" + "));
```

Please have a look at the function [parseHTML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/).

**Note of warning:** Never use [parseHTML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/) for untrusted sources!!! From the documentation:

> Most jQuery APIs that accept HTML strings will run scripts that are included in the HTML. jQuery.parseHTML does not run script in the parsed HTML unless keepScripts is explicitly true. *However, it is still possible in most environments to execute script indirectly, for example via the  attribute*. The caller should be aware of this and guard against it by cleaning or escaping any untrusted inputs from sources such as the URL or cookies.

Comment: Thanks for your input and information. However I am using Titanium, where it is not possible to use the `DOM`, so I think using JQuery will not work for this example. Do you know a workaround in just plain javascript?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But maybe you can find something similar to ``parseHTML`` in the API of titanium...